# Want to move windows sharepoint services 2 database from sql server 2005 to sql server 2008

Tags: windows, sharepoint, service

I Want to move windows sharepoint services 2 database which is currently running on sql server 2005 (Same server for WSS and sql server) to a separate Sql Server 2008 r2 (Clustered servers). The database has been copied, renamed and set up on a new clustered sql server 2008R2 server. It is running ok. It is the Windows SharePoint Services side that I need advice in what do I need to change on the IIS/SharePoint side to get my SharePoint Web site to work with the database on the 2008R2 clustered server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is entirely possible to move a database from SQL 2005 to 2008 and you have a number of options on how to do this:

- Detach, move and then attach the database files
- Perform a backup and restore from the old server to the new
- Use the copy database wizard on SQL 2008 to pull the database across from SQL 2005